# Getting dates from Firebase by days

Tags: reactjs, firebase, date

I want to get dates from Friebase where year, month and day is the same as my date, but the hours, minutes, seconds, etc. could be different. 
For example I have date - 15.05.2020 00:00:00 and I want to get all dates from firebase where is 15.05.2020, not matter which hour or minute.

Can I do such a things ?

Comment: Sure, you can certainly store a day of the year in a database. Having a time attached to that piece of data might not be helpful though.

Comment: You may want to consider just storing it a yyyymmdd format as a String if you never need the time component, or a separate field for just that string along with a date field. The string is easy to work with and can be easily queried and sorted.

Answer (score 1):

First, your field needs to have a type=timestamp so you can grab the date, which I believe you have done that already. As for the date formating you can use https://momentjs.com/ to customize the fetched date from firebase. Watch the tutorial on how to do that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sjbZXdGB6M&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iWstfXntcj8f-dFZ4UtlN3&index=31

Comment: Looks legit. I will check it tomarrow  for sure ;P